# How to start sync EOS with mainnet?

Tags: nodeos, mainnet, blocks

looks like EOS is not syncing? I can only see operators in log file and that's basically it.

I am starting with these params:

```
nodeos -e -p eosio \
--genesis-json='genesis.json' \
--plugin eosio::producer_plugin \
--plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin \
--plugin eosio::http_plugin \
--plugin eosio::state_history_plugin \
--filter-on="*" \
--access-control-allow-origin='*' \
--trace-history \
--chain-state-history \
--producer-threads='16' \
--chain-threads='16' \
--http-threads='16' \
--net-threads='16' \
--contracts-console \
--validation-mode=full \
--chain-state-db-size-mb=65536 \
--disable-replay-opts \
--sync-fetch-span='500' \
--state-history-endpoint='127.0.0.1:8080' \
--http-validate-host=false \
--p2p-peer-address='185.253.188.1:19876' \
--p2p-peer-address='api-full1.eoseoul.io:9876' \
--p2p-peer-address='api-full2.eoseoul.io:9876' \
--p2p-peer-address='boot.eostitan.com:9876' \
--p2p-peer-address='bp.cryptolions.io:9876' \
--p2p-peer-address='bp.eosbeijing.one:8080' \
--p2p-peer-address='bp.libertyblock.io:9800' \
--p2p-peer-address='br.eosrio.io:9876' \
--p2p-peer-address='eos-seed-de.privex.io:9876' \
--verbose-http-errors >> nodeos.log 2>&1 &
```

Here is the log:

```
info  2019-10-09T13:11:31.236 nodeos    net_plugin.cpp:1879           operator()           ] host: br.eosrio.io port: 9876 
info  2019-10-09T13:12:01.236 nodeos    net_plugin.cpp:1879           operator()           ] host: 185.253.188.1 port: 19876 
info  2019-10-09T13:12:01.236 nodeos    net_plugin.cpp:1879           operator()           ] host: api-full1.eoseoul.io port: 9876 
info  2019-10-09T13:12:01.236 nodeos    net_plugin.cpp:1879           operator()           ] host: api-full2.eoseoul.io port: 9876 
info  2019-10-09T13:12:01.236 nodeos    net_plugin.cpp:1879           operator()           ] host: boot.eostitan.com port: 9876 
info  2019-10-09T13:12:01.236 nodeos    net_plugin.cpp:1879           operator()           ] host: bp.cryptolions.io port: 9876 
info  2019-10-09T13:12:01.236 nodeos    net_plugin.cpp:1879           operator()           ] host: bp.eosbeijing.one port: 8080 
info  2019-10-09T13:12:01.236 nodeos    net_plugin.cpp:1879           operator()           ] host: bp.libertyblock.io port: 9800 
info  2019-10-09T13:12:01.236 nodeos    net_plugin.cpp:1879           operator()           ] host: eos-seed-de.privex.io port: 9876 
info  2019-10-09T13:12:01.236 nodeos    net_plugin.cpp:1879           operator()           ] host: br.eosrio.io port: 9876
```

Edit: looks like it need some time to start sync the blocks from operators (~30min):

```
info  2019-10-14T10:44:18.537 nodeos    producer_plugin.cpp:410       on_incoming_block    ] Received block 2df11845419d8ce4... #12993000 @ 2018-08-25T15:59:23.500 signed by libertyblock [trxs: 2, lib: 12992666, conf: 0, latency: 35837095037 ms]
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information? Which Version, self-compiled or package-install, operating-system, is the process stopping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a documentation on how to install an EOSIO Node to the latest vresion and sync properly to the mainnet: https://docs.liquidapps.io/en/v2.0/dsps/eosio-node.html

Comment: thanks! This is what I need.